# Does using typedef for an array take more memory than the array itself when allocated?

Tags: arrays, c, typedef

Simply, if I were to do:

```
typedef char arrayOne[10];
```

and in main:

```
char arrayTwo[10];
```

would `malloc(sizeof(arrayOne))` take more memory than `malloc(sizeof(arrayTwo))` ?

Or in other words; I'm using typedef to keep the code more simple, but is it worth it or I should just forget it because it uses unnecessary extra memory?

Comment: No, same size...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i was fearing maybe some extra bits to store information or something for the compiler

Comment: The typedef doesn't allocate any memory at all (or introduce overhead); it's just providing some information to the compiler for later use when you actually define some variables.

Comment: `typedef` just adds an *alias* of a type, it's handled internally inside the compiler, no trace of the type-alias will be seen in the finished executable code.

Comment: a typedef is an alias of an other type (in the large sense of the term)

Comment: regarding: `typedef char arrayOne[10];`  This is enabling the replacement of `char` (at any place in the following code) to be replaced by: `arrayOne[10]`  Probably not what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no relation between memory allocation & `typedef`. The keyword `typedef` simply creates aliases to make the long name datatypes into shorter & more meaningful to read.

Comment: That's very optimistic.  I've seen plenty of typedefs which make the code more obfuscated and harder to read.